# amdgpu-pro *ERROR* ring sdma0 timeout error on Ubuntu server 20.04.1 with HWE stack installed

Tags: kernel, hardware, gpu-driver, amdgpu-pro

I am using Ubuntu server 20.04.1. (kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic x86_64) with amdgpu-pro for my mining rig. After 24-48 hours I receive the following error message and the machine completely freezes:

```
[53990.091296] [drm:amdgpu_job_timeout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma0 timeout, signaled seq=425102, emitted seq=425103
[53990.098608] [drm:amdgpu_job_timeout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process ethminer pid 1106 thread ethminer 1106
[54016.509585] Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler
[54017.564573] Shutting down cpus with NMI
[54017.580849] Kernel Offset: 0x3000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff
[54017.585947] Rebooting in 30 seconds..
[54047.310232] ACPI MEMORY or I/O RESET_REG.
```

After that a hard reset is required.

I only installed amdgpu-pro (20.45-1188099-ubunut-20.04) with `./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=pal,legacy --headless` and the HWE stack.

Since I am pretty new to Ubuntu (and linux in general) I have no idea what causes the error. Could this be the indication of faulty/old hardware? The video cards have been running for more than 2 years (but used other OS before) now.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated. If more information is needed I am happy to provide those either.

Thanks